# Unity Multiplayer player synchronization

Tags: networking, mobile, synchronization, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am working on a unity mobile game. Which is like a multiplayer version of temple run. Because this game is meant for mobile there is a fluctuating latency generally in the range of 200ms - 500ms.
Since the path is predetermined and actions the user can perform are limited (jump,slide, use powerup etc) , the remote player keep running on the path until it receives the updated state from its local player. 
This strategy generally works pretty well since I only need to send limited amount of data over the network but there is a specific case in which I am having issues.
In the game, players die on the specific positions (obstacles).
 I want remote players to die on the same obstacle/position as local player but due to latency in sending message, the remote player crosses the obstacle by the time it receives the death message.
Is there a way to sync the players on the deaths. 
One of the things I tried was moving the remote player back to the local players death position but not only does it look awkward visually but can also raise other syncing issues.
Is there some other better way to do this ?

Comment: Interesting problem - Can you just clarify this statement a bit "I want remote players to die on the same obstacle/position as local player" ?

Answer (score 0):

One way I may recommend is to make one player acts like server (not real server). The server-player will do all the computation like moving, jumping, creating scenes, etc. Then the server-player will send all the data to sync with the client-player. The client-player get the data and process game state. The client-player can also send his action (left-right-jump-slide) to the server-player. This way both player will have the same state of the game like position, die. You also need to deal with latency by adding some prediction.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I implemented was I spawned all the remote player behind enough so they can have some time to receive the information that local player was died on specific obstacle. And in the end there is a straight path where I just sync players again. So that result is displayed correctly.